# Looping two audio objects with a pause in between each one

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've got two audio elements on a page:

```html
<audio id="voice1" class="voice1 voice" controls>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="voice1" class="voice2 voice" controls>
    <source src="2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I want to play the first one, pause for 5 seconds, play the second one, pause for a further 5 seconds then repeat the whole process a fixed number of times.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
        var audioArray = document.getElementsByClassName('voice');
        var i = 0;
        audioArray[i].play();
        for (i = 0; i < audioArray.length - 1; ++i) {

            audioArray[i].addEventListener('ended', function(e){
            // pause here for 5 seconds
            var currentSong = e.target;
            var next = $(currentSong).nextAll('audio');
            if (next.length) $(next[0]).trigger('play');

        });
    }
});
```

I have experimented with setInterval and setTimeout but I can't get this pause to work. I have considered just playing a quiet mp3 file for 5 seconds but this seems daft. Can anyone recommend a suitable approach?

Comment: Show us your "experiment" and tell us how it fails.

Comment: I "experimented" with putting the functions in the **// pause here for 5 seconds** place, and they failed insofar that the script didn't pause.

Comment: Please show us your code as your tried it. Stack Overflow is all about learning from your errors...